# vbscript: how to convert a date into days and time

Tags: vbscript

I have last boot time from WMI and it looks as '20141103113859.220250+060'. i want to convert it to number of days and time from the current time.

is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

From Help

> Use the SWbemDateTime object to convert these to regular dates and times. 
>   Windows 2000/NT and Windows 98/95:  SWbemDateTime is not available. To convert WMI dates to FILETIME or VT_DATE format or to parse the date into component year, month, day, hours, and so on, you must write your own code.

```
Set dtmInstallDate = CreateObject( _
    "WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject( _
    "winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set objOS = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
    "Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
For Each strOS in objOS
    dtmInstallDate.Value = strOS.InstallDate
    Wscript.Echo dtmInstallDate.GetVarDate
Next
```

To get help.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363

Install the Windows SDK but just choose the documentation.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that I confirmed via the MSDN 2003 library that SWbemDateTime is first available on Windows XP and Windows Server 2003. Anything older will not have it.

Answer (score 4):

Next simple function should work for any argument in valid [CIM_DATETIME format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387237(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
Function WMIDateStringToDate(dtmDate)
WMIDateStringToDate = ( Left(dtmDate, 4) _
    & "/" & Mid(dtmDate, 5, 2) _
    & "/" & Mid(dtmDate, 7, 2) _
    & " " & Mid(dtmDate, 9, 2) _
    & ":" & Mid(dtmDate,11, 2) _
    & ":" & Mid(dtmDate,13, 2))
End Function
```

An example:

```
InstallDate (wmi): 20141205231553.000000+060
InstallDate:       2014/12/05 23:15:53
```

However, a `wmi` query could return `Null`, e.g. `VarType(dtmDate)=1` for a particular instance of a date; in next script is the function modified:

```
option explicit
Dim strWmiDate
strWmiDate = "20141103113859.220250+060"
Wscript.Echo strWmiDate _
  & vbNewLine & WMIDateStringToDate(strWmiDate) _
  & vbNewLine & DateDiff("d", WMIDateStringToDate(strWmiDate), Now) _ 
  & vbNewLine _
  & vbNewLine & WMIDateStringToDate(Null) _
  & vbNewLine & DateDiff("d", WMIDateStringToDate(Null), Now) 



Function WMIDateStringToDate(byVal dtmDate)
  If VarType(dtmDate)=1 Then
      WMIDateStringToDate = FormatDateTime( Now) 'change to whatever you want
  Else
      '
      ' to keep script locale independent:
      ' returns ANSI (ISO 8601) datetime format (24 h)
      '
      ' yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS
      '
      WMIDateStringToDate = Left(dtmDate, 4) _
          & "-" & Mid(dtmDate, 5, 2) _
          & "-" & Mid(dtmDate, 7, 2) _
          & " " & Mid(dtmDate, 9, 2) _
          & ":" & Mid(dtmDate,11, 2) _
          & ":" & Mid(dtmDate,13, 2)
  End If
End Function
```

Output:

```
==>cscript 29535638.vbs
20141103113859.220250+060
2014-11-03 11:38:59
157

09.04.2015 15:36:38
0
```

Comment: It's a very good idea to 'to keep script locale independent'. But by returning a **string** from WMIDateStringToDate (and not a date as the name promised) you have to hope that all calculations/implicit conversions in the calling code succeed for all locales. Use DateSerial + TimeSerial instead.

Answer (score 3):

@Serenity has given this same answer while i was writting, but ...

```
Option Explicit

    WScript.Echo getLastBootUpTime()
    WScript.Echo WMIDate2Date( "20141103113859.220250+060" )
    WScript.Echo GetElapsedTime( getLastBootUpTime(), Now )

Function WMIDate2Date( ByVal WMIDate )
    With WScript.CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")
        .Value = WMIDate
        WMIDate2Date = .GetVarDate(False)
    End With 
End Function     

Function getLastBootUpTime()
Dim oOS
    For Each oOS In GetObject( "winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2").ExecQuery("Select LastBootUpTime from Win32_OperatingSystem")
        getLastBootUpTime = WMIDate2Date(oOS.LastBootUpTime)
    Next
End Function

Function GetElapsedTime( ByVal Date1, ByVal Date2 )
Dim seconds, aLabels, aValues, aDividers, i
    aLabels = Array( " days, ", ":", ":", "" )
    aDividers = Array( 86400, 3600, 60, 1 )
    aValues = Array( 0, 0, 0, 0 )
    i = 0
    seconds = Abs( DateDiff( "s", Date1, Date2 ))
    Do While seconds > 0 
        aValues(i) = Fix( seconds / aDividers(i) )
        seconds = seconds - aValues(i) * aDividers(i)
        aValues(i) = CStr(aValues(i)) & aLabels(i)
        i=i+1
    Loop
    GetElapsedTime = Join(aValues, "")
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

You won't get around splitting the WMI date string to make it to a date string that VBScript understands. Try this:

```
<%

    wmiDate  = "20141103113859.220250+060"

    ' note i am using date format: [m/d/Y H:m:s]
    ' if you prefer other format, i.e. [d.m.Y H:m:s] switch mid offsets
    fromDate = Mid(wmiDate,5,2) & "/" & Mid(wmiDate,7,2) & "/" & Left(wmiDate,4)
    fromTime = Mid(wmiDate,9,2) & ":" & Mid(wmiDate,11,2) & ":" & Mid(wmiDate,13,2)

    toDate = Date & " " & Time

    response.write(DateDiff("d",fromDate & " " & fromTime,toDate) & " Days<br />")
    response.write(DateDiff("h",Date & " " & fromTime,toDate) & " Hours<br />")

%>
```

It uses `Mid()`and `Left()`functions  to split WMI date into the needed parts for VBScript. Then the `DateDiff()` function will deliver the interval difference first for `d`= days and then for `h`= hours. You will notice when calculating hours i just used the time part of the WMI string, since we already calculated days difference, we only want hours left over.

Interesting article explaining [VBScript Date and Time (Iso Formats)](http://www.merlyn.demon.co.uk/vb-date1.htm#IF)

As a comment was so *kindly* remarking the date format i used and the result of the hour calculation, i added a comment line explaining the date format i used *(i used `m/d/Y H:m:s` but depending on your local, you might prefer `d.m.Y H:m:s` then you need to swap the `Mid()` offsets to get the right order)*. I also appended the current `Time` to the `toDate` and in the hour calculation prepended the current `Date` to calculate the correct time difference.

Comment: With your solution i think DST will not be considered.

Comment: @rora for timezone one could easily parse the last three digits and subtract them from the minutes '-Mid(wmiDate, 23)' as [explained here](http://www.merlyn.demon.co.uk/vb-date1.htm#IF). So you can get more accurate just with string and date functions without other scripting object.

Comment: This code is totally useless. The positions for the time parts are wrong, the "h" calculation fails because fromTime has a datepart from 1899.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner thank you for your wording. I just wanted to point out a possible solution and hence provided links for further reading - and yes, fromTime should actually just be added with current date, i apologize, since i just wanted to point out the tools and did not pay too much attention in actual correctness of the hour outcome.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner ah, now i understood, i thought you where commenting the date format itself - thanks for the note - counted wrong there by one offset which is fixed now