# CDate format creating problems in diff date

Tags: vbscript

I am not good with `VBS`. Basically, I need to calculate the numbers of hours passed since the computer uptime.

This is what I have:

```vb
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colOperatingSystems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")

Set nTime = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * From Win32_LocalTime")


For Each objOS in colOperatingSystems
    dtmBootup = objOS.LastBootUpTime
    dtmLastBootupTime = WMIDateStringToDate(dtmBootup)
    thisday = Date
    thistime = Time
    nowTime = Month(thisday) & "/" & Day(thisday) & "/" & Year(thisday) & " " & Hour(thistime) & ":" & Minute(thistime) & ":" & Second(thistime)
    dtmSystemUptime = DateDiff("h",dtmLastBootUpTime,nowTime)

    if dtmSystemUptime >= 24 then
        MsgBox("Restarting computer as machine has been up for " & dtmSystemUptime & " hours. Last-Uptime: " & dtmLastBootupTime & ". Now: " & nowTime)
    exit for
    end if

Next

' returns in mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss format
Function WMIDateStringToDate(dtmBootup)
    WMIDateStringToDate = (CDate(Mid(dtmBootup, 5, 2) & "/" & _
        Mid(dtmBootup, 7, 2) & "/" & Left(dtmBootup, 4) _
            & " " & Mid (dtmBootup, 9, 2) & ":" & _
                Mid(dtmBootup, 11, 2) & ":" & Mid(dtmBootup,13, 2)))
End Function
```

Well this works fine when deployed on some of the client computers. But there is a problem in few.

If the local windows setting is in `dd-mm-yyyy` format, then my `WMIDateStringToDate` interprets  `CDate("2020/07/11 12:00:00")` as `7 Nov` instead of `11 July`. And hence there is a problem in the difference.

How do I make sure that, before I compare dates, they are in the same format

Comment: Don't use `FormatDateTime()` as it relies on the regional settings of the OS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vbscript: how to convert a date into days and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29535638/vbscript-how-to-convert-a-date-into-days-and-time). *(This question relates specifically to WMI Date / Times the title isn't very clear)*.

Comment: @Lankymart tried without FormatDateTime as well.Doesnt work

Comment: @Lankymart the suggested solution also has the same problem as shown above.

Comment: Which one? Suggest looking at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29536404/692942) which makes sure the value is returned locale independently. Would also recommend [using `DateSerial()` and `TimeSerial()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29535638/vbscript-how-to-convert-a-date-into-days-and-time#comment47240344_29536404) to keep it locale-independent.